# is there any method to quickly draw a shortest distance path on a mesh from one point to the other?

Tags: add-on

shortest distance problem

Any addon to achieve this? Thanks a lot.

screenshot:

https://app.yinxiang.com/fx/f2ccf92a-7079-4fe3-b6f0-cda289efcd0f

Comment: if you use the knife, won't it give what you want?

Comment: Or 'J' between 2 selected vertices. Both of these cut the projection of a straight line. But I think NOLAN  may be looking for a [geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic).

Comment: Absolutely, Robin, i want to auto-generate the geodesic on any mesh, how to achieve this?